# Need to populate an email referencing the latest data in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, lookup, ampscript, date

I'd like to insert content based on a user's last entry within a Data Extension; that is, if a user looked at five products over five days, I want to use the most recent product to insert content.   The Data Extension is a transactional DB in that all the records are present - so how do I write the AMPscript to review all the rows but only action on the most recent one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with the assumption you have a field in your Data Extension that has a date data type. I'll call it `ViewDate`

You'll need to use the [LookupOrderedRows](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/) AMPscript Function and do something like this:

```
%%[

SET @rowset = LookupOrderedRows("MYDENAME, 1,"ViewDate Desc","SubscriberKey", SubscriberKey)

IF RowCount(@rowset) > 0 THEN

SET @productName = FIELD(ROW(@rowset, 1), "ProductName")

ENDIF

]%%
```

I'm looking up the Data Extension and retrieving only 1 row, where the SubscriberKey matches and the latest ViewDate. I'm then creating a variable that will be populated with the Product's name.